# Contact Form Sending Error

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I'm screwing around with a template and just trying to get my contact form to work (in attempt to see how it works, sends messages, etc.). When filling out my contact form and then hitting submit, instead of it going through successfully, one of the errors pops up:

> Email could not be sent due to some Unexpected Error. Please Try Again later.
>
> Reason:
> Could not instantiate mail function.

http://prntscr.com/fh5cct

Here's my contact form in HTML:

```
<div class="col_half col_last">

    <div class="fancy-title title-dotted-border test-john">
        <h3>Send us an Email</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="contact-widget">

        <div class="contact-form-result"></div>

        <form class="nobottommargin" id="template-contactform" name="template-contactform" action="include/sendemail.php" method="post">

        <div class="form-process"></div>

        <div class="col_one_third">
            <label for="template-contactform-name">Name <small>*</small></label>
            <input type="text" id="template-contactform-name" name="template-contactform-name" value="" class="sm-form-control required" />
        </div>

        <div class="col_one_third">
            <label for="template-contactform-email">Email <small>*</small></label>
            <input type="email" id="template-contactform-email" name="template-contactform-email" value="" class="required email sm-form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="col_one_third col_last">
            <label for="template-contactform-phone">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" id="template-contactform-phone" name="template-contactform-phone" value="" class="sm-form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div class="col_full">
            <label for="template-contactform-subject">Subject <small>*</small></label>
            <input type="text" id="template-contactform-subject" name="template-contactform-subject" value="" class="required sm-form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div class="col_full">
            <label for="template-contactform-message">Message <small>*</small></label>
            <textarea class="required sm-form-control" id="template-contactform-message" name="template-contactform-message" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="col_full hidden">
            <input type="text" id="template-contactform-botcheck" name="template-contactform-botcheck" value="" class="sm-form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="col_full">
            <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit-button" tabindex="5" value="Submit" class="button button-3d nomargin">Submit Comment</button>
        </div>

        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

Then I have the sendemail.php file:

```
<?php

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$toemails = array();

$toemails[] = array(
                'email' => 'myEmail@yahoo.com', // Your Email Address
                'name' => 'My Name' // Your Name
            );

// Form Processing Messages
$message_success = 'We have <strong>successfully</strong> received your Message and will get Back to you as soon as possible.';

// Add this only if you use reCaptcha with your Contact Forms
$recaptcha_secret = 'your-recaptcha-secret-key'; // Your reCaptcha Secret

$mail = new PHPMailer();

// If you intend you use SMTP, add your SMTP Code after this Line


if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    if( $_POST['template-contactform-email'] != '' ) {

        $name = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-name'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-name'] : '';
        $email = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-email'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-email'] : '';
        $phone = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-phone'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-phone'] : '';
        $service = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-service'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-service'] : '';
        $subject = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-subject'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-subject'] : '';
        $message = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-message'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-message'] : '';

        $subject = isset($subject) ? $subject : 'New Message From Contact Form';

        $botcheck = $_POST['template-contactform-botcheck'];

        if( $botcheck == '' ) {

            $mail->SetFrom( $email , $name );
            $mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );
            foreach( $toemails as $toemail ) {
                $mail->AddAddress( $toemail['email'] , $toemail['name'] );
            }
            $mail->Subject = $subject;

            $name = isset($name) ? "Name: $name<br><br>" : '';
            $email = isset($email) ? "Email: $email<br><br>" : '';
            $phone = isset($phone) ? "Phone: $phone<br><br>" : '';
            $service = isset($service) ? "Service: $service<br><br>" : '';
            $message = isset($message) ? "Message: $message<br><br>" : '';

            $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>This Form was submitted from: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

            $body = "$name $email $phone $service $message $referrer";

            // Runs only when File Field is present in the Contact Form
            if ( isset( $_FILES['template-contactform-file'] ) && $_FILES['template-contactform-file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {
                $mail->IsHTML(true);
                $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES['template-contactform-file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['template-contactform-file']['name'] );
            }

            // Runs only when reCaptcha is present in the Contact Form
            if( isset( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ) {
                $recaptcha_response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
                $response = file_get_contents( "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . $recaptcha_secret . "&response=" . $recaptcha_response );

                $g_response = json_decode( $response );

                if ( $g_response->success !== true ) {
                    echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Captcha not Validated! Please Try Again." }';
                    die;
                }
            }

            $mail->MsgHTML( $body );
            $sendEmail = $mail->Send();

            if( $sendEmail == true ):
                echo '{ "alert": "success", "message": "' . $message_success . '" }';
            else:
                echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Email <strong>could not</strong> be sent due to some Unexpected Error. Please Try Again later.<br /><br /><strong>Reason:</strong><br />' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '" }';
            endif;
        } else {
            echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Bot <strong>Detected</strong>.! Clean yourself Botster.!" }';
        }
    } else {
        echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Please <strong>Fill up</strong> all the Fields and Try Again." }';
    }
} else {
    echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "An <strong>unexpected error</strong> occured. Please Try Again later." }';
}

?>
```

Which requires this autoload.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * PHPMailer SPL autoloader.
 * PHP Version 5
 * @package PHPMailer
 * @link https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/ The PHPMailer GitHub project
 * @author Marcus Bointon (Synchro/coolbru) <phpmailer@synchromedia.co.uk>
 * @author Jim Jagielski (jimjag) <jimjag@gmail.com>
 * @author Andy Prevost (codeworxtech) <codeworxtech@users.sourceforge.net>
 * @author Brent R. Matzelle (original founder)
 * @copyright 2012 - 2014 Marcus Bointon
 * @copyright 2010 - 2012 Jim Jagielski
 * @copyright 2004 - 2009 Andy Prevost
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html GNU Lesser General Public License
 * @note This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful - WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 */

/**
 * PHPMailer SPL autoloader.
 * @param string $classname The name of the class to load
 */
function PHPMailerAutoload($classname)
{
    //Can't use __DIR__ as it's only in PHP 5.3+
    $filename = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class.'.strtolower($classname).'.php';
    if (is_readable($filename)) {
        require $filename;
    }
}

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.2', '>=')) {
    //SPL autoloading was introduced in PHP 5.1.2
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '>=')) {
        spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload', true, true);
    } else {
        spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload');
    }
} else {
    /**
     * Fall back to traditional autoload for old PHP versions
     * @param string $classname The name of the class to load
     */
    function __autoload($classname)
    {
        PHPMailerAutoload($classname);
    }
}
```

---

Edit: Looks like I must edit/change a few lines of code here and input more data.

> If you are not receiving Emails from your Forms then chances are that your Server Configuration doesn't support PHP mail() function. But you can use SMTP Authentication.

So I can add the following under `$mail = new PHPMailer();`:

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "mail.yourdomain.com";
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 26;
$mail->Username = "yourname@yourdomain.com";
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";
```

This gives me a few more questions now. What's the `mail` in `mail.yourdomain.com` ? Is the User/Pass for cPanel, my Email, what?

Comment: are you trying this on a local server?

Comment: I think you need to set additional properties on your PHPMail $mail instance -- unless you omitted those for the sake of security.

Comment: @DCR No on my live hosted site || Magnus Eriksson - does that mean I need to change value in form to 'POST' instead of 'SUBMIT' ? || Landen I didn't make it, so not entirely sure what that entails

Comment: No, I misspoke, looked at the wrong line. Deleted my comment.

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/a3b4f6b2815fd5e5142cbb006a36cb69a86525b7/class.phpmailer.php#L1493 is this the PHPMailer class you are using? If so it looks like it's using the `mail()` function to send mails, maybe you need to check if it's set up properly in `php.ini`.

Comment: @Havenard Looks like I might have to do this: `If you are not receiving Emails from your Forms then chances are that your Server Configuration doesn't support PHP mail() function. But you can use SMTP Authentication.` Which looks like I have to set up, rather input, a user and password - is that the user and pass to my cPanel/email/other?

Comment: Possibly, I would advise you not to use `mail()` anyway so either way it's worth a shot.

Comment: @Havenard and All || Edited OP with more information that I don't entirely understand if someone can explain that to me! :)

Comment: `mail.yourdomain.com` would be the address for the SMTP server (it doesn't necessarily start with `mail.`), user and password would be the credentials for using it, and port is either 25 or 587. Using this method will allow you to send from any e-mail account, you can even use a GMail.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but where do I find this address, user and password to my SMTP server? Never heard of, used, or seen something like this - thus why I decided to try and read through it :o Do I use cPanel from my website's host?

Comment: It got nothing to do with the cPanel credentials, but you probably can use cPanel to create this e-mail account if your server features that service. It should be telling there whats the IMAP, POP3 and SMTP addresses to set up this e-mail on any device, so you can just grab the SMTP address from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146114/discussion-between-john-barr-and-havenard).

Comment: who is your host provider?  I have code for godaddy,bluehost,c9.io, and web000

Comment: @DCR currently using namecheap

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I set it up on Bluehost:

```
function mailerExpressBlueHost(array $mailInputs){

         require_once '../includes/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

         $mail = new PHPMailer();
         $mail->IsMail();

         $mail->SetFrom('skipper@yourdomain.com'); // make sure this is an andress 
                                                 // on your domain        
         $mail->IsHTML(true);
         $mail->addAddress($mailInputs['addAddress']);    
         $body = $mailInputs['body'] ;              
         $mail->isHTML(true);
         $mail->Subject = $mailInputs['subject'] ;
         $mail->Body    = $body;

         if(!$mail->send()) {
            return 'Message could not be sent.' . 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;  
         } else {
            return 'Message has been sent';
         }

          $mail->ClearAddresses();
}
```